Dealing with QGIS freezing when executing PyQGIS script
I want to create a tool that allows me to use a source layer to retrieve the parcels contained in the selected commune from my PostgreSQL database.
When I use layer actions, everything works fine. But when I use the QGIS processing code editor, the software crashes.
# Importer les modules nécessaires

def tr(self, string):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

def createInstance(self):
    return ImportParcellesTest()

def name(self):
    return 'import_parcelles_test'

def displayName(self):
    return self.tr('Import Parcelles Test')

def group(self):
    return self.tr('Custom Scripts')

def groupId(self):
    return 'customscripts'

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT_LAYER, self.tr('Input Layer'), [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField(self.INPUT_FIELD, self.tr('Field'), parentLayerParameterName=self.INPUT_LAYER, type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Any))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.INPUT_VALUE, self.tr('Value')))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.DB_HOST, self.tr('Database Host')))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber(self.DB_PORT, self.tr('Database Port'), type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, defaultValue=5432))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.DB_NAME, self.tr('Database Name')))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.DB_USER, self.tr('Database User')))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.DB_PASSWORD, self.tr('Database Password')))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    feedback.pushInfo("Début de l'importation des parcelles.")

    # Récupération des paramètres
    layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_LAYER, context)
    field = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_FIELD, context)
    value = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_VALUE, context).strip()
    db_host = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.DB_HOST, context)
    db_port = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, self.DB_PORT, context)
    db_name = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.DB_NAME, context)
    db_user = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.DB_USER, context)
    db_password = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.DB_PASSWORD, context)

    # Création de la chaîne de connexion
    try:
        layer_name = f"Parcelles - {value}"
        uri = (f"dbname='{db_name}' host={db_host} port={db_port} user='{db_user}' "
               f"password='{db_password}' sslmode=disable "
               f"table=\"cadastre_rpcu_2024\".\"parcelle_info\" (geom)")
        feedback.pushInfo(f"URI de connexion : {uri}")
        
        # Chargement de la couche
        parcelles_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, layer_name, "postgres")
        if not parcelles_layer.isValid():
            raise QgsProcessingException("Échec de l'importation de la couche des parcelles.")
        
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(parcelles_layer)
        feedback.pushInfo(f"Couche '{layer_name}' importée avec succès.")

        # Appliquer le filtre pour la commune
        filtre = f"TRIM(nomcommune) ILIKE '{value}'"
        parcelles_layer.setSubsetString(filtre)
        feedback.pushInfo(f"Filtre appliqué : {filtre}")

        # Vérification du résultat du filtre
        if parcelles_layer.featureCount() > 0:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Filtrage réussi", f"Parcelles affichées pour la commune {value}", level=Qgis.Success)
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Aucune parcelle trouvée", f"Aucune parcelle trouvée pour la commune {value}", level=Qgis.Warning)
    except Exception as e:
        feedback.reportError(f"Erreur : {str(e)}")
        raise QgsProcessingException(f"Erreur lors de l'importation : {str(e)}")

    feedback.pushInfo("Fin de l'importation des parcelles.")
    return {}

Do you have any ideas about the problem?

When you say "the software crashes", are you getting any error messages? Does it freeze (if so for how long?) and you have to force quit, or does it immediately crash and close on it's own?

One second after I run it, it freezes before I get any error message, then crashes. It closes on its own

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags
